# What's the "standard" way to express a zero/null morpheme in an interlinear gloss in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, linguistics

I'm interested in what the "norm" is for the field.

I tried both  `$\oslash$` and `$\emptyset$`, but neither looks normal... or maybe I'm over thinking this.  Is there a standard in linguistics publications?

e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme

Comment: *zero morp...* who?

Comment: Maybe `\varnothing`?

Comment: Could you edit your question, to include pictures and/or links describing what you want. Maybe this is relevant?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme

Comment: On [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme), it's  ``varnothing` (U "2205) that is used.

Comment: On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme, it's `\varnothing` (U "2205) that is used.